# How should i improve this function?

Tags: c

How should i improve this function to be albe to be ordering a linkedlist? when i use this Ordering function, does not swapping the elements in the linkedlist properly.
// Ordering function

```
Naplo* Ordering(Diary* List)
 {
     Diary* Temp;
     Diary* Moving;
     if (List== NULL)
         return;
     for(Temp = List; Temp != NULL; Temp = Temp ->NextDiary)
     {
         for (Moving = Temp -> NextDiary; Moving != NULL; Moving = Moving -> NextDiary)
         {
             if (Temp -> Time.h < Moving->Time.h 
                 || (Temp->Time.h == Moving->Time.h
                  && Temp->Time.m < Moving->Time.m))
             {
                 Naplo* Swapping = Moving;
                 Moving = Temp;
                 Temp = Swapping;
             }
         }
     }
     return List;
 }
```

It does not swapping the items properly.

Comment: Hi could we have a [MCVE], read also [ask].

Comment: it looks that you try to order a collection by two scalar values: `a < b iff a.h <= b.h && a.m < b.m`. This is a **partial ordering** because it is not defined for all pair of elements. Try `a={.h =1, .m = 2}` and `a = {.h = 2, .m = 1}`. Neither `a<=b` nor `b <= a`. Therefore the problem you try to solve is likely ill-posed.

Comment: To begin with, have it return the same type as you declared it to return. And fix your compiler so you don't have to waste so much time chasing down already found errors, see [What compiler options are recommended for beginners learning C?](https://software.codidact.com/posts/282565).

Comment: Its from a structure: typedef struct Datum
{
    int ev, honap, nap;
} datum;


typedef struct Ido
{
    int ora, perc;
} ido;


typedef struct naplo
{
    datum datum;
    ido ido;
    char nev[50];
    char helyszin[50];
    char megjegyzes[100];
    struct naplo *Kovnaplo;
} Naplo; sry that i didn't translate the values to english